# The meaning of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, tree, hierarchical-data

I'm working with hierarchical data in my cms. My `menu` table is this:

`id` || `name` || `lft` || `rgt`

[image: hierachical-data]

And my `left` and `right` columns are:

[image: Tree]

To retrieving a full tree and it's depth, I've found this query:

```
SELECT node.id, node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                                FROM menu AS node,
                                menu AS parent
                                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                                GROUP BY node.name
                                ORDER BY node.lft;
```

There is a join, table with itself.
How dose it retrieve whole tree?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not just read the tutorial from which you obtained this graphic?

Comment: @Strawberry There is not enough explanation for the meaning of query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do hierarchical queries in a tree with SQL, you need a special data model.

Your example uses the [Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).